# Unable To upload file to google drive - using c#

Tags: c#, google-oauth, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-client

All code runs without errors, but when I check my Google Drive account I can't find the file I am uploading ("document.txt").

Also it has asked me for Authentication again.

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
   new ClientSecrets
   {
       ClientId = "Here my clientid",
          ClientSecret = "client secret",
   },
   new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
   "user",
   CancellationToken.None).Result;

// Create the service.
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
});

File body = new File();
body.Title = "My document";
body.Description = "A test document";
body.MimeType = "text/plain";

byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("document.txt");
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
request.Upload();

File file = request.ResponseBody;
```

Questions:
Why cant I find my uploaded file, and how can I get it to remember my authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are forgetting [body.Parent](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) so it doesn't know what directory to place the file into.

> parents[] list    Collection of parent folders which contain this file.
>   Setting this field will put the file in all of the provided folders.
>   On insert, if no folders are provided, the file will be placed in the
>   default root folder.

example:

```
body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = 'root' } };
```

You are getting asked for authentication again because you aren't saving authentication.

```
//Scopes for use with the Google Drive API
string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                                 DriveService.Scope.DriveFile};
// here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
UserCredential credential = 
            GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker
                          .AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = CLIENT_ID
                                                            , ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET }
                                          ,scopes
                                          ,Environment.UserName
                                          ,CancellationToken.None
                                          ,new FileDataStore("Daimto.GoogleDrive.Auth.Store")
                                          ).Result;
```

FileDataStore stores the authentication data in the %appdata% directory.

More detailed information can be found in the tutorial [Google Drive API with C# .net – Upload](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/)

Update For the following error:

> "The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or
>   per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request
>   does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers
>   Console to update your configuration. [403]"

Go to Developer console for your project [here](https://console.developers.google.com/project/)  Under APIs & auth  ->  APIs  enable Google drive API and sdk.  Also go to credentials and make sure you added a product name and email.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I will do suggested changes

Comment: You can find the sample project to go along wit the tutorial here https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-Drive

Comment: not working. I have added body.parents with id="root" and also tried with some existing folder in my drive. Still i don't find my file in drive. Authentication issue is gone. Did i miss something in code.

Comment: root should be the top level of your drive account.  If you want a different directory your going to have to use files list. To find the directory ID of the directory you want to upload to.

Comment: Also give it the path to "document.txt"  example c:\document.txt.  Bet your stream is empty.

Comment: I executed your code(Git-hub) for google drive. And i dont see my file in my drive. I think i have to do something with my Google account.

Comment: Probably not just debug your way though it. Make sure its building the filestream.  check what it returns.

Comment: getting this error
  "The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration. [403]"

Comment: Updated answer. you need to enable it in the console app

Comment: thanks. Its working now, i have enable drive sdk service. Its works.